# converting a list to dictionary of dictionary in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I found few advice in this site regarding how to convert a list into a dictionary. I have successfully followed it. But i got struck in performing a conversion  from a list to dictionary of dictionary; like graph representation

```
    I/p: 0,0,1,1,0,4
    o/p: 0:{1:0,2:1}---------------------->1:0 means 1 is vertex and 0 is weight
         1:{0:1,2:4}
```

Here, keys represent the vertices of graph.

Can you please advice me, how to resole this issue?

THank you

Comment: Can you explain your input and output better?

Comment: So from vertex 0 there's an edge to vertex 1, weighted 0. Right?
How is this implied from the input?

Comment: @OfirIsrael: U s RIGHT. actually i take the string input from the user and do some string to integer conversion and save the input into a list. NOW i want to convert the list into a dictionary of dictionary

Comment: Yeah, but how do you understand that there should be this edge from the string "0,0,1,1,0,4" (or from the list [0,0,1,1,0,4] for that matter)

Comment: @OfirIsrael: if u divide the list by 2 u will get no. of vertices(here it is 3). Now if i iterate the list i will get that from 0 to 0 there is no edge(weight 0).0 to 1 there s no edge also and frm 0 to 2 theres a edge of value 1. My plan is to going in this manner. wht u thnk?

Comment: It looks like the input breaks in to triplets where the first value is the weight to vertex 0, the second to vertex 1, and the third to vertex 2, from the triplet indexed (if you will) vertex.  How do you know how many vertices there are to map this though?  How do you know, for instance, that this isn't a weight map for a single vertex with 5 neighbors?

Comment: @user2015915 I think this is not a good way to represent the graph.. If it's weighted then an edge that weighs 0 is also an edge.. There's a difference between a '0' edge and no-edge...

Comment: @SilasRay: I give u an instance of my list. I ADMIT THAT, i am bit confuged to decide whether i take matrix to dictionary of dictionary conversion or from list to dictionary of dictionary conversion. If I have a list of 8 numbers, I assume that there are 4 veritices which are connected in a brute manner of thinking.

Comment: @user2015915 That's wrong...

Comment: Shouldn't there be 9 entries for this case? Why are there no edges listed from `2`?

Comment: @OfirIsrael: at my  input/output sample i follow the way you mention. As 0 has no edge to itself I did not add it there. and u r right, theres no 0 weight...

Comment: Where does your list come from? Did you come up with this graph representation yourself? If you can decide how to represent the graph, I would definitely go for a matrix (or list of lists) where each row is a vertex and each entry in the row is the connection weight to another vertex. The matrix should be square. This way there can be no misunderstandings.

Comment: Or you could go for a list of tuples where each entry is (source vertex, target vertex, connection weight).

Comment: @Robᵩ: u r right . there are 9 entries. 0 1 2 1 0 3 2 2 0. What i am presently doing, I convert alredy the list into a matrix form of [[0 1 2],[1 0 3],[2 2 0]] it gives me the row length,column length.But I again got struck how to do this dictionary prsentation

Comment: It's sounding more and more like you are trying to solve your higher level problem in a suboptimal way, and asking for help to fix a problem that only arises because your original methodology is flawed.  Can you fully describe your goal and how the system as a whole works?

Comment: @SilasRay: Actually i am not running for a large system. I am trying to take graphs input as a list and tries to convert them into the format i have shown in the output sample.

Comment: Why are you trying to take this input as a list?  Are you taking it from user input?  Do you control the user input flow, or are you forced to consume this list from an interface you don't control?

Comment: @SilasRay:I am just trying to play with the list and dictionary. User will give input from command line and I have a code to control the user input, so to get the input in right order.

Comment: So why not just build your map on the fly based on user input?  Instead of taking an obtusely formatted comma delimited string of numbers, ask the user how many vertexes there are, create a data structure to fit, then run through each edge and prompt the user to enter the weight for that edge.  If you want to condense it, ask for the weights for each edge from each vertex in a single prompt.  What you have now just doesn't seem to make life easier for your users or for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to represent the graph differently. The user input should be a matrix.

Item (i,j) in the matrix should be X if there's an edge weighted X from vertex i to vertex j, and be (let's say) "-1" if there isn't. (This is all interchangeable of course).

```
    0    1    2

0  -1    0    1

1   1   -1    4

2   1    4   -1
```

So the input string should be like:
`-1,0,1;1,-1,4;1,4,-1`

Afterwards, use `collections.defaultdict` ([documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)) like so:

```
>>> d = defaultdict(dict)
>>> input = '-1,0,1;1,-1,4;1,4,-1'
>>> lst = map(lambda x: map(lambda y: int(y), x.split(',')), input.split(';'))
>>> for i,j in enumerate(lst):
...     for k,l in enumerate(j):
...             d[i][k] = l
...
>>> d
defaultdict(<type 'dict'>, {0: {0: -1, 1: 0, 2: 1}, 1: {0: 1, 1: -1, 2: 4}, 2: {
0: 1, 1: 4, 2: -1}})
```

Comment: heh, took me a while.

Comment: `None` is probably better for the placeholder than `-1`.  Something non-numeric.

Answer (score 2):

> > *I convert alredy the list into a matrix form of [[0 1 2],[1 0 3],[2 2 0]] it gives me the row length,column length.But I again got struck how to do this dictionary prsentation*

```
mx = [[0, 1, 2],[1, 0, 3],[2, 2, 0]]
md = { i:
       { j:v for (j,v) in enumerate(sublist) if i != j }
       for (i,sublist) in enumerate(mx)
     }
print (md)
```

Comment: You need to filter the inner dict by the outer index to exclude the loopback edges he apparently does not want.

Comment: @Robᵩ: thanx a lot. yet i did nt get the proper output. My input is: 0,1,1,1,0,2,1,2,0 and the output shoud be:{ 0: {1: 1, 2:  1},1: {2: 2},2: {}} . I understand that this is a same representation what i deserve. THanx after all

Comment: @user2015915 - I don't see how *anything* you've said previously indicates that is the correct output. Why does `2` have any empty dict? What happened to edge from 1 to 0 with weight 1?

Comment: Wait, do you only want a weight value in the output for a higher-indexed vertex if the edge weight between it and it's lower indexed neighbor is asymmetrical?  I think you really need to refine your problem statement and re-examine your basic user flow and data structure.